# Is there a basic guide to creating themes in Burg?

Tags: themes, customization, burg

I have a basic theme idea I'd like to create in burg.

I can find some information about customizing existing themes in burg, but not a basic tutorial that shows you how to create your own unique theme.

Can anyone point me towards some resources?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the wiki. It might be a good place to poke around.

http://code.google.com/p/burg/wiki/ThemeCustomization